# OpenCL enqueueReadBuffer throwing out of resources error

Tags: c++, opencl

New to OpenCL here.

I have this code written in C++ OpenCL below:

```
cl::Kernel kernel_Hist = cl::Kernel(program, "hist_simple");

kernel_Hist.setArg(0, buffer_A);
kernel_Hist.setArg(1, buffer_B);
kernel_Hist.setArg(2, count);
kernel_Hist.setArg(3, minValueal);
kernel_Hist.setArg(4, maxValueal);

queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_Hist, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(vector_elements), cl::NDRange(local_size));
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, vector_size, &outputFloat[0]);
```

the last line seems to be throwing case -5 (OUT_OF_RESOURCES) error. I just do not seem to understand how it actually hits this error. I was debugging over the variables and they seem to have values.

Any guidance would be much appreaciated

Comment: `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error is sometimes an indication of an out-of-boundaries access in a kernel code. You can check if this is your case by removing a body of `hist_simple` kernel: if the error goes away, then some operation reads or writes outside of allocated buffers.

Comment: Your local size could be too large, have you checked that the implementation supports the requested group size for that particular kernel?